# nltk frequency combining singular and plural, verb and adverb when tokenizing

Tags: python, nltk

I want to count frequency but I want to combine singular and plural forms of nouns and verbs and their adverb forms. Excuse the poor sentence. For example: "That aggressive person walk by the house over there, one of many houses aggressively."

Tokenize and count frequency

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
test = "That aggressive person walk by the house over there, one of many houses aggressively"
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(test)
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
common=fdist.most_common(100)
```

Output: 
`[('houses', 1), ('aggressively', 1), ('by', 1), ('That', 1), ('house', 1), ('over', 1), ('there', 1), ('walk', 1), ('person', 1), ('many', 1), ('of', 1), ('aggressive', 1), ('one', 1), ('the', 1)]`

I want `house` and `houses` to be counted as `('house\houses', 2)` and `aggressive` and `aggressively` to be counted as `('aggressive\aggressively',2)`. Is this possible? If not, how do I proceed to make it look like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **lemmatize**.

NLTK includes a WordNet-based lemmatizer:

```
import nltk
tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
test = "That aggressive person walk by the house over there, one of many houses aggressively"
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(test)
lemmas = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(t) for t in tokens]
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(lemmas)
common = fdist.most_common(100)
```

This results in:

```
[('house', 2),
 ('aggressively', 1),
 ('by', 1),
 ('That', 1),
 ('over', 1),
 ('there', 1),
 ('walk', 1),
 ('person', 1),
 ('many', 1),
 ('of', 1),
 ('aggressive', 1),
 ('one', 1),
 ('the', 1)]
```

However, *aggressive* and *aggressively* are not merged by the WordNet lemmatizer.
There are other lemmatizers out there, which might do what you want.
For a start, though, you might want to consider stemming:

```
stemmer = nltk.stem.PorterStemmer()
stems = [stemmer.stem(t) for t in tokens]
nltk.FreqDist(stems).most_common()
```

Which gives you:

```
[(u'aggress', 2),
 (u'hous', 2),
 (u'there', 1),
 (u'That', 1),
 (u'of', 1),
 (u'over', 1),
 (u'walk', 1),
 (u'person', 1),
 (u'mani', 1),
 (u'the', 1),
 (u'one', 1),
 (u'by', 1)]
```

The counts look alright now!
You might, however, be irritated by the fact that the stems don't necessarily look like real words...